# Fill a particular vector drawable with a gradient (or a solid color)

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

Ok so I have a vector drawable which is an irregular shape made out of a combination of `path`s which I need to fill with a background. Now, how can I go about doing that?

For example, a simple square made out of four paths like so

108 x 108 canvas:-

```
<path 
      android:pathData="M10,10 98, 10"/>


<path 
      android:pathData="M98,10 98, 98"/>

<path 
      android:pathData="M98,98 10, 98"/>

<path 
      android:pathData="M10,98 10, 10"/>
```

Now how do I fill this shape up?

Thanks

PS: If there is an alternative, with which I can do this declaratively with jetpack compose, please.

PPS: Please note, this is just an example, while the actual shape that I have is highly unsymmetrical (geometrically) and consists of around 10 `path`s

Comment: Are you talking about *fill* or *stroke*. If *fill*, should the area between the paths be filled up?

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I wanted.

Comment: what about tint?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only option is to combine the different paths into one. Here I have done that, removed the "M"s and added a "z" in the end.

```css
svg>path {
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M10,10 98, 10"/>
  <path d="M98,10 98, 98"/>
  <path d="M98,98 10, 98"/>
  <path d="M10,98 10, 10"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g1">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="purple" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="orange" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M10,10 98,10 98,10 98,98 98,98 10,98 10,98 10,10 z" fill="url(#g1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: If no instruction after the beginning point of the path ("M x,y") and several points are given what is used by default - "L"? I mean absolute coords for straight line?

Comment: @Leonid I guess so. On [d - SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#moveto_path_commands) is says: "Any subsequent coordinate pair(s) are interpreted as parameter(s) for implicit absolute LineTo (L) command(s)".